# C# arrays compared to C++ arrays and the garbage collector

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm a C++ programmer trying to wrap my head around C# and found something I'm concerned about.
To declare an array, you have to use the New operator right?
But wont that get the garbage collector involved?

Hypothetically if I had a function that was creating an array just for use within that function and it was being called thousands of times per frame, wouldn't all those calls to the New operator create a significant overhead for the garbage collector?

In C++ these would be arrays declared on the stack that would drop out of scope as soon as the function ends and the performance overhead would be minimal but in C# I'm worried how much performance the garbage collector might take up in this case.

So am I thinking about this the right way?
Is the garbage collector involved here and will it cause problems?
Is there a better "C# way" to do this?

Comment: GC is only called when it is necessary. It won't be called after your function call

Comment: All those little calls to `new` do, in fact, add overhead. The garbage collector however would not need to run each time your method terminates. Garbage collection only runs "once in a while". However, if this is really a concern, make the array a class member so it can be reused.

Comment: I just tested this and I was right. 1000 calls per frame to the New operator causes a huge overhead in the GC. I profiled it and found the GC was taking 87% of a frame and dropped the framerate from ~60 to ~30.

Comment: More likely that `new` was taking up that time and not GC, for reasons that have been explained here.

Comment: Okay but that raises the question still: how do you efficiently create an array in C# if the only way to do so is use the "New" operator? or are they just inefficient now?

Comment: If you *really* need stack-allocated arrays, you can use `stackalloc`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx

Comment: Are you allocating so much memory per frame that the GC is running all the time or are you calling GC.Collect() yourself?

Comment: you could also just reuse a buffer as well,  if its threaded, then you can reuse it from thread local storage

Comment: I wasn't calling GC.Collect() in my test. This was purely a hypothetical, not a problem I'm actually having at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, don't worry about the garbage collector, it knows what it's doing and it's really good at it.

If you are doing image stuff, then yes, you may run into problems... you can step around this though,  for instance you can use stackalloc  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx

but it means your code will have to be set to "unsafe".

```
int* frameData;
frameData = stackalloc int[200];
```

Comment: well, other than reusing the same buffer.

Comment: @Mloren, when testing make sure to check out about "large object heap" (LOH) behavior - if you allocate arrays of 80K+ you'll get different bafavior compared to smaller arrays. On migration pains: C# arrays are close to stl::vector than to int[234].